# How do I use content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a dynamic page title. Is more then just @project.title

The project title, in the page title contains many elements, like the project name, the project category and the project city.

I've tried this

```
<%= content_for :page_title @project.name, @project.category, @project.city %>

<%= content_for :meta_description, @project.description %>
```

But I get an error like this one

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
```

I've also tried

```
<%= content_for (:page_title @project.name, @project.category, @project.city) %>
```

which resulted in the same error: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## quick answer

Maybe, just try this in your Project view

```
<% content_for :page_title, "#{@project.name} #{@project.category} #{@project.city}" %>
```

## tl;dr

`content_for` stores a bit of code in an identifier. In order to access this stored content later you have to pass the identifier as an argument to `content_for`.
Note: yield can still be used to retrieve the stored content.

Or in other words, the `content_for` method allows you to insert content into a named yield block in your layout.

#### for example

If your current layout contains a `yield(:title)` ...

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="title"><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "No title block!" %></div>
  <div id="main"><%= yield %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can insert a title from a view like this

```
<!-- app/views/projects/index.html.erb -->
<% content_for :head do %>
 "#{@project.name} #{@project.category} #{@project.city}"
<% end %>
```

See: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for
and https://rubyplus.com/articles/3081-Layouts-and-Content-For-Tag-in-Rails-5

To answer your question. The error messages you receive tell you that your Ruby code is syntactically incorrect. In idiomatic ruby, it's always wrong to call functions the way you've shown us. Parameters must always be called individually, separated by a comma:

```
# wrong code, wrong syntax
<%= content_for :page_title @project.name, @project.category, @project.city %>
```

```
# wrong code, right *right syntax*
<%= content_for :page_title, @project.name, @project.category, @project.city %>
```

Also as pointed out in Robin's answer, the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) for `content_for` show that you can only pass one content parameter. So you have to do the concatenation by yourself.

```
<% content_for :page_title, "#{@project.name} #{@project.category} #{@project.city}" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's just a syntax error. If you want to store a block you use `<% content_for :page_title, "My title" %>`. Only if you want to reuse this block, you should add a `=` after the opening tag.

According to the docs you can only pass one `content` parameter. So you have to do the concatenation by yourself.

```
<% content_for :page_title, "#{@project.name} #{@project.category} #{@project.city}" %>
```

The documentation for the `content_for` helper can be found [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for).